# Java wildcard generics' return type in a method

Tags: java, generics

This is perhaps the nth time I get confused about wildcards in generics so Im seeking your help. Please look at the code below.

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Thread> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(new Thread());
        l.add(new Thread());
        m1(l);
    }

     static <T extends Runnable> Collection<T> m1(ArrayList<T> l) {
        ArrayList<Thread> r = new ArrayList<>();
        return r;
    }
}
```

When I call m1, I can pass `ArrayList<Runnable>` or any of its implementing classes and it works. So far all is fine. Now within the method `m1`, Im unable to return `ArrayList<Thread>` or `ArrayList< Runnable>` because the return type is `Collection<T>`. My confusion is, `T` is bounded by either `Runnable` or any of its implementing classes and that's why I can't send `ArrayList<String>` when calling m1. If the compiler is smart enough to know that, why would not it know that `ArrayList<Thread>` is a valid return argument for this method `m1`?

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't return an `ArrayList<Thread>` in place of a `ArrayList<T>`: it's not the same type. If you want to return an `ArrayList<Thread>`, make the return type `ArrayList<Thread>` (or a supertype, e.g. `Collection<Thread>`).

Comment: @AndyTurner yes wwhile I understand ArrayList<Thread> and ArrayList<T> is different what I dont understand is, I have T bounded as either Runnable or it's implementing type. So clearly, ArrayList<Thread> is still within the bounded type and valid for Collection<T>, right?

Comment: No: *they're not the same type*. `T` can be *any* subclass of `Runnable`, as chosen by the *caller*.

Comment: Don't you just want `ArrayList<T> r = new ArrayList<>();` ?

Comment: Well yes @Michael but trying to understand why what Im doing does not work.

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner. That makes sense!

Comment: @InfiniteLoop If I have a `class Foo implements Runnable`, then T is taken as `Foo`. Therefore the return is `Collection<Foo>`. `ArrayList<Thread>` is not a `Collection<Foo>`

Comment: yep! got it. Thanks @Michael :)

Comment: @InfiniteLoop It sounds like your return type should probably just be `Collection<Thread>`, unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182802/discussion-between-infiniteloop-and-michael).

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain, if compiler will allow you to return `ArrayList<Thread>` instead of `ArrayList<T>` it means you can call method with another subcalss of Runnable but still you will get `ArrayList<Thread>`.

For example lets say that you have another implementation of Runnable as `MyThread` and you are calling your method `m1` as `m1(new ArrayList<MyThread>)` which means `T=MyThread.class` in the same time your method returns another implementation of Runnable `ArrayList<Thread>` which will lead to RuntimeException

So, generics that is why here to prevent you from future runtime exceptions

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Andy and @Michael in comments, the type of the actual variable returned should be exactly the same as the the return type defined in the function signature.

It cannot be just a subtype of it as you wrote in your code, because if a user of your function was calling it with `T` defined as `Runnable` for example, your return type just won't match the actual return type which would be `Collection<Runnable>`.

So you should write your function like this:

```
    static <T extends Runnable> Collection<T> m1(ArrayList<T> l) {
        ArrayList<T> r = new ArrayList<>();
        return r;
    }
```